# JComponent only displays partially

Tags: java, swing

I am currently attempting to create a very simple game, but I quickly ran into a problem. The box it's supposed to draw is only partially displaying. It seems like it can only display in a limited area, but I have no idea what would have caused this or how I can solve it.

```
public class Game 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Game game = new Game();
  }

  public Game()
  {
    JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel somePanel = new JPanel();
    Box testBox = new Box(10, 10, 20, 20);
    somePanel.add(testBox);
    gameFrame.add(somePanel);
    gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gameFrame.add(testBox);
    gameFrame.setResizable(true);
    gameFrame.setBounds(500, 500, 600, 350);
    gameFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

the class with main

```
public class Box extends JComponent
{
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private int width;
  private int height;

  public Box(int x, int y, int width, int heigth)
  {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = heigth;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
      g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
  }
}
```

and the class that is('nt) drawing the rectangle.
Note: This is my first time using Stackoverflow, so if I did anything wrong, please tell me.

Here is an image of the frame:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PT9Yg14.png]

Drawing the box with a class extending JPanel seems to work, it's not what I wanted, but at least it works.

Comment: Please format (indent) your code properly, and post a complete minimal program that reproduces the problem. This code doesn't compile, and if I rename g2d to g, then it works fine (although somePanel is useless, sinceyou add the box to it, but then immediately after add it to the frame itself). Also, respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: You're adding testbox twice - once to somepanel, once to gameframe.

Comment: @Kylar Just tried removing that line, but it seems like nothing has changed.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with your layouts. JPanel uses FlowLayout (IIRC) and JFrame uses BorderLayout. Try removing somePanel alltogether and add testBox to the JFrame.

Comment: I added testBox directly to the JFrame, still the same thing. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/PT9Yg14.png) is a screenshot, in case it would help. @Kylar

Comment: Your program has no problem and works like this - you should be looking to find the problem somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

> This is my first time using Stackoverflow...

Screenshots should be included with the question so we can see the image without clicking on it. As a new user I don't think you include the image, but you can include the link as part of your question. Someone will general add the image to the question for you.

The code works fine for me when the Box component is added directly to the frame.

The image you provide doesn't make any sense. The size of your painted lines are much larger than 20 pixels so the image does seem to match your posted code. Make sure the image is generated when executing the posted code.

Normally when doing custom painting you would override the `paintComponent(...)` method of `JPanel` and invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` as the first statement. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples. Especially note how you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method. If you don't then the layout managers will think the size is (0, 0) so there will be nothing to paint.

If you don't extend a JPanel then you are responsible for painting the background of your JComponent since there is no default painting done. Basic code might be something like:

```
g.setColor( getBackground() );
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
g.setColor( getForeground() );
g.drawRect(...);
```

Also, don't call your class Box. There is a Swing component already by that name so it will get confusing. The class name should be more descriptive.